# Android LinearLayout: not displaying correct height

Tags: android, xml, background, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout with a white background,filled with a bunch of LinearLayouts and RelativeLayouts. I've tried to set the parent layout to have a minimum height, but it still seems to be wrapping to the content.

Here's a picture of what it looks like now. The white space should have a set minimum height that is greater than it is now.
[image]

Here's what I think is a relevant section of the xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contactViewScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ABABAB" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/contactHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#EDEDED"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fullName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="175dip"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#D6D6D6"
                android:contentDescription="@string/contact_image_description"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mobilePhoneHeading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/mobile_phone"
                android:textColor="#787878" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mobilePhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

... and many other LinearLayouts, all set to 'GONE' programmatically.

Can anyone suggest a fix? I can't figure out why that white section is taking up so little space.

Comment: Quick note: there are two views with the same "@+id/image". Which won't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// try this
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contactViewScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ABABAB" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/contactHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#EDEDED"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fullName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="175dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image"
                    android:background="#000000" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="#D6D6D6"
                    android:contentDescription="contact_image_description"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mobilePhoneHeading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:text="mobile_phone"
                    android:textColor="#787878" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mobilePhone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

set the height in second linearlayout. now it is set as wrap content.. do like

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"  //for example
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobilePhoneHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/mobile_phone"
            android:textColor="#787878" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobilePhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving it a go now.

Comment: It didn't seem to fix it, but it's probably something in my code.

Answer (score 1):

It can be because of the device size too. I'd definitely suggest using linear layout's weight. That should make it perfect on all the devices irrespective of tablet or phone.

Let me know if you want any more guidance, or if you have any issues with weight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't even think to use weight so that's great to know.